# start without inheritance of parents file descriptors

Tags: shell, windows-xp

I need to start some process on winXP with "start" command.
Sounds simple.

But is there a way that the started process would not inherit any ports from parent?

I start children in my program using:

```
system "start x -params"
```

Now when parent is being killed, I can't start it again because I'm learned by errors that some process is already occupying port (which killed parent was using).

I don't want to use:

- createProcess (from winAPI, where this can be setup to not inherit fds)
- use python in my start string (or any similar interpreters)

Is there a way to start my child process in a way I want them to start?

Is there any "start" alternative?

Answer (score 1):

So after diggin a while, i've found:

> psexec

with commandline like:

> psexec -d -s myprogram > logfile.log 2>&1

everything is solved.

Comment: Thanks very much for posting the answer, this solved a problem I had with spawning another process from Hudson. The problem is described at http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Spawning+processes+from+build but that page does not suggest psexec.

Answer (score 0):

```
powershell -command "Start-Process myprogram.exe"
```